# Carol Marcus learning about David after The Search for Spock

Tags: star-trek, the-search-for-spock

In *The Search for Spock*, Kirk's son David Marcus gives his life on the Planet Genesis, after Captain Kruge orders his men to execute one of the three prisoners (David, Saavik, and Spock).

**Is there any information, perhaps in the Extended Universe, as to how and when Carol Marcus learns of the circumstances of David's death?**

Presumably, she would have been told initially by Starfleet that David likely perished aboard the USS Grissom, the science vessel that he and Saavik had transferred to, which was destroyed in orbit of Genesis by Kruge.

Kirk may have been unable to contact Carol directly during his three-month exile on Vulcan, and so perhaps Sarek or Saavik contacted her in the first instance regarding the truth.  But this is just speculation on my part.

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1078437.Star_Trek_IV) for "The Voyage Home" we learn that Carol Marcus has been avoiding Saavik's and Kirk's communications. Both assume that she has already learned of David's death through official Starfleet channels.

> Jim took a deep breath. "This is Jim Kirk again." He had been trying
> to call Carol Marcus since the morning after his arrival on Vulcan.
> Every time, he had failed to reach her. By now she must know of the
> death of her son David. It both relieved and distressed Jim that he
> would not be the one to tell her. But he had to talk to her.
>
> "It's extremely urgent that I speak with Carol," he said. "Please have her call me as soon as possible."

As far as her learning the ***specifics*** of David's death, this is covered in some detail. Suffice to say, her grief is nearly indescribable:

> "We know," Verai said. "And we are grateful that you came to us. We
> will speak of them, and remember them. But we must speak of someone
> else as well."
>
> Holding Carol's hands, Verai and Kirim told her of
> the death of her son.
>
> Shocked speechless with grief and horror, Carol sank to the floor and
> stared at the window's light. The pattern crept across the floor with
> the motion of the sun. In the warmth of the hall she started to
> shiver.   "Come with us, Carol," Verai said. "We will grieve for our
> partners, and we will grieve for your son."
>
> In a visitors' chamber
> of the habitation, Lieutenant Saavik of Starfleet also failed to reach
> Carol Marcus.

Comment: Thanks, Richard.  I'm pretty good with most Trek names, even some of the most obscure, but who are Verai and Kirim?  And where is the habitation that the second excerpt refers to?

Comment: According to the novel, Verai and Kirim were partners to Jedda and Zinaida (David Marcus' assistants in Star Trek II) *"Two Deltans waited for her, a woman and a man, Verai Dva-Payjh and Kirim Dreii-dall. Partners was the closest word in Standard to describe the relationship of these two people to Zinaida and Jedda. They had formed a professional and economic and sexual partnership that should have lasted for decades."*

Comment: She was on [Planet Delta IV](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delta_IV) when she was given the details of David's death.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Comment: She was speechless? I think the appropriate response is, "You Klingon bastards, you killed my son! You Klingon bastards, you killed my son! You Klingon bastards, you killed my son!" ...etc.

Comment: @KSmarts - Or the classic "Noooooooo!!!!" stare at the ceiling shaking her fists.